# PHP foreach statement

Tags: php

I am a student with PHP and I have a question from this course I am taking which I am able to produce my own solution which works, however the course uses some sort of "fill in the blank" testing method on their web page which means parts of the code cannot be edited.

Basically I have this right now:

```
<?php

$myArray = array(2,4,6,8);

foreach($myArray as $value)

    echo "Points are $value\n";

?>
```

But it prints "Points are 2 Points are 4 Points are 6 Points are 8"... It needs to print Points are 2 4 6 8 (so print a value with each loop with a space). I know that there is a method that measures the number of arrays against what is being printed before it stops, however I haven't been able to figure it out.

EDIT: Here is the actual question from the webpage of my school's course:

```
<?php

$numberstring = $_GET['numberstring'];
$numberarray = explode(',',$numberstring);

//your code here

echo "Points are $value\n";  
?>
```

Comment: Echo the "Points are" part outside the loop

Comment: You can ['implode'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the contents of the array into a string to stick on the end of your output.

Comment: `echo "Points are 2 4 6 8";` :)

Comment: There are still multiple ways to do this (`$value = str_replace(","," ",$numberstring)`, ignoring the array entirely) or as already pointed out, use implode() (`$value = implode(" ", $numberarray)`) or more convoluted possibilities. You can also use a foreach to concatenate as a string if that's the requirement (`$value;foreach($numberarray as $number){$value .= $number." ";}`) --- you have to pick the way that answers the question since we can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put them together you can join them.

```
echo 'Points are ', implode(' ', $myArray), PHP_EOL;
```

Edit:

After you updated your question, use this as answer to the 2nd part:

`$points` is empty, so you can directly use implode on `$numberrray`.

```
echo 'Points are ', implode(' ', $numberarray), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I can't edit the line where "echo" is.... this assignment is pretty weird, and I got it to work on my own computer but not on the webpage where the course is held (since part of the code can't be edited). I think it's better that I paste how the question was phrased:

<?php

    $numberstring = $_GET['numberstring'];
    $numberarray = explode(',',$numberstring);



//your code here

echo "Points were: $points\n";
?>

Comment: `$points` is empty. If you only can edit the echo-line, try `echo 'Your points are ', implode(' ', $numberarray), PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly. So the teacher expected us to have an understanding of both explode  and implode functions for this.

Answer (score 2):

Foreach loops do *everything* in the loop, every time. Easy mistake, you'll get used to it.

```
<?php

$myArray = array(2,4,6,8);

echo "Points are ";
foreach($myArray as $value)

    echo $value." ";

?>
echo "\n";
```

See Markus Zeller's answer for a better way to do this, if your predefined code templates allow it.